# Complex function using Parse Server Cloud Code (looping and creating records)

Tags: parse-server, parse-cloud-code

After a night of trial and error I have decided on a much simpler way to explain my issue.  Again, I have no JS experience, so I don't really know what I am doing.

I have 5 classes:

- **game** - holds information about my games
- **classification** - holds information about the user classes available in games
- **game_classifications** - creates a one game to many classifications relationship (makes a game have mulitple classes)
- **mission** - holds my mission information
- **mission_class** - creates a one to many relationship between a mission and the classes available for that mission

Using Cloud Code, I want to provide two inputs through my Rest API being missionObjectId and gameObjectId.

The actual steps I need the code to perform are:

- Get the two inputs provided `{"missionObjectId":"VALUE","gameObjectId":"VALUE"}`
- Search the game_classifications class for all records where game  = gameObjectID
- For each returned record, create a new record in mission_class with the following information:
- - mission_id = missionObjectId
- - classification = result.classification

Here is an image of the tables:
[image]

And here is how I have tried to achieve this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("activateMission", async (request) => {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    const query = new Parse.query('game_classifications');
    query.equalTo("gameObjectId", request.params.gameObjectId);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < query.length; i ++) {
        const mission_classification = Parse.Object.extend("mission_class");
        const missionClass = new mission_classification();
        
        missionClass.set("mission_id", request.params.missionObjectId);
        missionClass.set("classification_id", query[i].classificationObjectId);
        return missionClass.save();
    }
});
```

Does anyone have any advice or input that might help me achieve this goal?

The current error I am getting is:

```
Parse.query is not a constructor
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Give it a try in cloud code and share what you've tried. It might be easier to help.

Comment: Thanks @DaviMacêdo.  I have updated the above with everything I tried last night, also added a graphical representation of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems on your current code:

- `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` does not exist for quite a long time. Use `useMasterKey` option instead.
- It's `Parse.Query` and not `Parse.query`.
- You need to run `query.findAll()` command and iterate over it (and not over query).
- For performance, move `Parse.Object.extend` calls to the beginning of the file.
- To access the field of an object, use `obj.get('fieldName')` and not `obj.fieldName`.
- If you return the save operation, it will save the first object, return, and not save the others.

So, the code needs to be something like this:

```js
const mission_classification = Parse.Object.extend("mission_class");
const game = Parse.Object.extend("game");

Parse.Cloud.define("activateMission", async (request) => {
    const query = new Parse.Query('game_classifications');

    const gameObj = new game();
    gameObj.id = request.params.gameObjectId;

    query.equalTo("gameObjectId", gameObj);
    
    const queryResults = await query.findAll({useMasterKey: true});

    for (let i = 0; i < queryResults.length; i++) {        
        const missionClass = new mission_classification();
        
        missionClass.set("mission_id", request.params.missionObjectId);
        missionClass.set("classification_id", queryResults[i].get('classificationObjectId'));
        await missionClass.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @davi.  I have used your code above, and now it doesn't throw any errors and says Ran cloud function activateMission for user and shows the inputs and Result: undefined but it's not actually doing anything.  I tried adding try { } catch(err) { } inside the loop but that doesn't show anyhing. I even tried return ("Classification ID ", queryResults[i].get('classificationObjectId')); do you know how I can get some sort of output to see where it is falling down?

Comment: I guess the query is not returning any result and therefore not going through the loop. I've just seen that `gameObjectId` is a pointer, so you can't just passe the id to the query. You need to pass a game object. Just edited the code.